# how to implement EnumClass::$userInput on php 8.1 Enums?

Tags: php, laravel, enums, solid-principles, php-8.1

I have been learning the new enums introduction on php 8.1 with laravel for an eccomerce cms. i'm brandly new on `SOLID` principles.

This this my Enum class:

```
enum PaymentMethods : string
{
    case PAYPAL  = 'pay with paypal';
    case STRIPE  = 'pay with stripe';
}
```

On checkout page user can select one of Payment Methods like this:

```
<select name="delivery_method">
    @foreach(DeliveryMethods::cases() as $case)
        <option value="{{ $case->name }}">{{ $case->value }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

let's assume that we have `PAYPAL` value (which is taken from user input), in the view and we want to access the value of `PAYPAL` from PaymentMethods Enum class,

one method is that i use a foreach loop like this:

```
<p>
    @foreach(DeliveryMethods::cases() as $case)
        @if(request()->get('payment_method') == $case->name)
            {{ $case->value }}
        @endif
    @endforeach
</p>
```

but i want to use this logic in different places and on many times,
is there any better way instead of doing this, based on solid prinsiples?

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten your code by using one of the methods provided for [backed enums](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.backed.php) and the nullsafe and null coalesce operators.

```
{{ DeliveryMethods::tryFrom(request()->get('payment_method'))?->value ?? 'some default value' }}
```

You can use `from(...)` instead of `tryFrom(...)` if you want your code to fail if an invalid enum value is passed instead of dealing with nulls.

This is assuming you are using the **values** to access the cases. If you are using the name then it gets trickyer. You can implement static methods in enums:

```
enum PaymentMethods : string
{
    case PAYPAL  = 'pay with paypal';
    case STRIPE  = 'pay with stripe';
    
    public static function fromName(string $method): PaymentMethods
    {
        foreach(PaymentMethods::cases() as $case) {
           if ($case->name === $method) {
              return $case;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
PaymentMethods::fromName(request()->get('payment_method'));
```

[Example](https://3v4l.org/bbuX6#v8.2.3)

You can also move that method to a helper class somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```
PaymentMethods::{$selected_method}->value
```

> Note: here `$selected_method` is the value you obtain from view by user.

or you can define a `method` in your `enum class`. In that method, you will pass a `delivery method` name as a string and that method will evaluate the value of a selected method. i.e.

###### Define that method in the enum class

```
public function getVal($method)
{
   $this::{$method}->value;
}
```

###### call it anywhere by this way

```
PaymentMethods::getVal("PAYPAL");
```